# Sampling for making a correlation in R

Tags: r, function, correlation, sampling

I have the following data (it is a short example):

```
a=c(110.3,126.6,101,7,105.6,111,131.4,109.7,99.5,107.3)
b=c(210,47.5,234.5,223.9,213.4,250.1,198.3,180.3,170.9,118.9)
c=c(0.6,0.9,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.8,0.5,0.4,0.6)

val= cbind(a,b,c)
val=as.data.frame(val)
```

And I want to generate a sample with a function (a correlation between a and b)
So I have the following function:

```
acc_func <-function(myVal){
  newPop = sample(myVal,nrow(myVal), replace=TRUE)
  return((cor(newPop$a, newPop$b)^2)/mean(newPop$c))
}

results = matrix(,ncol=1,nrow=0)
for(i in 1:1000){
  accNow = acc_func(val)
  results = rbind(results,accNow)
}

head(results)
```

But for some reason that I don´t understand, R returns the following message:

```
Error in cor(newPop$a, newPop$b) : 
supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you run `sample(myVal,nrow(myVal), replace=TRUE)` alone? When putting `val` as a variable inside it like `sample(val,nrow(val), replace=TRUE)` it gives a strange output. So, I did not understand your aim about this line of code.

Comment: I hadn't realized that, but you're right, that part gives a strange result. I just want to sample randomly to make the correlation with the command that follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a size argument inside your `acc_func()` to determine the sample size as follows,

```
acc_func <-function(myVal,size){
  newPop = myVal[sample(1:nrow(myVal),size=size,replace=T),]

  return((cor(newPop$a, newPop$b)^2)/mean(newPop$c))
}


results = matrix(,ncol=1,nrow=0)
for(i in 1:1000){
  accNow = acc_func(val)
  results = rbind(results,accNow)
}


head(results)
```

gives,

```
            [,1]
accNow 0.1008954
accNow 0.2389546
accNow 0.3955409
accNow 0.1851096
accNow 0.1526633
accNow 0.3613495
```

Comment: Thanks maydin for your suggestion! However, if I do not add the 7 (acc_func(val,7)) I get only one number repeated 1000 times, that is a result that I got previously... And with the 7, the results are not ok, because the numbers that return are not possible for my data.

Comment: So change 7 for something else, it is all up to you. This is sampling. Sample size cannot exceeds the number of the rows. Even If you are OK with replacing the values, then the picture will not change as well since correlation does not care about replacing, It gives the very same result weather you are replace the rows again and again or not.